# how to get latest Image from folder using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, uploadify

I am using jquery's Uploadify to upload images on server. Now what i am doing when user successfully upload a image, i want to replace this image with the old one. for that i am binding the image **onsuccess** method of uploadify, it is working fine if the image's name is always different then the previous one, but if the image's name is same as the old one it not refreshing the image, its still showing the old image.here is my code:

```
   var WishId = "";
   var ImagePath = $('[id$=hdnImgPath]').val();
   var DefaultImagePath = $('[id$=hdnDefaultImagePath]').val();
   $("[id$=fpFiles]").uploadify({
       'swf': 'Swf/uploadify.swf',
       'uploader': 'Resources/Handlers/UploadProfilePic.ashx',
       'progressData': 'speed',
       'cancelImg': 'Images/Grid_ActionDelete.gif',
       'fileSizeLimit': '1MB',
       'fileTypeExts': '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
       'auto': true,
       'multi': false,
       'buttonText': 'Select',

       'onSelect': function () {
           WishId = $('[id$=hdnWishId]').val();
           $('#lnkUpload' + WishId).show(250);
       },
       'onUploadStart': function (file) {
           $("[id$=fpFiles]").uploadify('settings', 'formData', { 'WishID': "'" + WishId + "'" });
    },
    'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
        data = data.replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
        if (data != '') {
            alert(data);
            $('[id$=imgUsersProfilePic]').attr('src', ImagePath + data);
            // $('#hdnImageName' + WishId).val(data);
        } else {
            $('#img' + WishId).attr('src', DefaultImagePath + 'defaultProfile.png');
        }
    }
});
```

Please let me know what i have to do to display the latest image without post back, one thing more when i refresh my page its displaying the latest image.let me know where am i wrong.

**Update:**  i know this image is coming from cache but i cannot delete the cache, if i it will delete users session too. so i need some alternate...

Comment: Visions, does my solution work?

Comment: @PulkitMittal i knew that already please read my question carefully. by the way thanks for quick reply and for your effort too

Comment: yes, so you can add something like 
ImagePath + data + '?v=' + Math.random()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a random number at the end of the image right after you show it there, so at the moment is still loading and work with it, is always force to load it again.

```
$('[id$=imgUsersProfilePic]')
     .attr('src', ImagePath + data + '?' + Math.random());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try versioning the images once you change them.

Eg: for defaultProfile.png, replace it with defaultProfile.png?v=1 in the javascript code. This will fetch the latest image from the server and not from the cache.